# Action Actuactor interrupting Motion Actuator

Tags: game-engine

I have a character thats move forward by Motion Actuator but I need to make an accurate jump, so I made the jump movement by animation. In the "Jump" Action I've deleted the X and Y curves so only the Z curve will affect the character. I put it on a Action actuator and enabled the "Add" and the "Local" modes. but when my character jumps it cuts all the other movements, even the gravity, it don't affect the rotations thought, but I imagine if I put a Action whith rotation curves, will happen.
I'm going to need make a lot of objects movements based in animation. Help?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using an armature rig for your character. In Blender it is possible to play different animations at the same time, if they don't requier the same bone of your armature. So for example doing an action with the arms while walking shouldn't be a problem.

Therefore you need to move one of your animations to another animation layer.

[image]

I'm not sure how you've set up your character, but I hope it helps!

Comment: actually I put the Jump action on a Cube thats is the colision bound of the character, parent of the armature and body mesh, both set to no colision. So I put all the controls on this cube. If I put the Jump on the armature visually it works but the colision cube won't move.

Comment: short question: are you doing the jump animation with the integrated option "jump" in the Character Motion type of the Motion-logic brick? Or have you created a jump animation on your own?

Comment: Do I understand you right that your character consists of three different objects: an armature, a mesh and a cube for collision. And you're wondering why the collision box of the cube doesn't change when you're character moves?

Comment: The setup part you got right. I uploaded my file, I had no time yet to simplify it https://www.4shared.com/s/fLUCg9Wgkca  (X) acceleration, (A) hop, (arrows) turning. The Hop control is in the Logic State Layer number 2

Comment: The jump is made by animation

Comment: Could you please upload your .blend file to eg http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ , the solution from stackexchange. I had trouble to download your file bc of all that spam and ads on that website...

Answer (score 0):

I solved, To make Game dinamic movements based in animation curves you must use "Delta Transforms", in "object's properties tab" to make the animation of the jump for example, In "Action Actuator" don't active the "add" and "local" buttons it won't interrupt other dynamics motions of the object.